# Trying to write a program to sum the value of an int and a char

Tags: c, integer, character

I am trying to write a program in C to sum the value of an integer and a character. If the user enters an integer where the character should be, I am expecting my program to calculate the value of the 2 integers. My code below works with the user entering 2 integers but only calculates up to 9 (Ex: 4 5: "Character '4' represents a digit. Sum of '4' and '5' is 9"). If the user enters 5 6, the result is: "Character '5' represents a digit. Sum of '5' and '6' is ;". I have been searching for a while now and any potential solution always leads to the incorrect sum. I also expect my program to accept user input higher than '9' (Ex: 20 50), but if I change '9' to '99', I get the following warning: "warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]". Can someone please point me in the right direction to achieve these goals?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum (int m, char n){
    return m+n;
}

int main(){
    char ch;
    int c;
    printf("Enter an integer and a character separated by a blank> ");
    scanf("%d %c",&c, &ch);
    if((c >= '0' && c <= '9')||(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')){
        int cs = sum(c, ch - 0);
        printf("Character '%d' represents a digit. Sum of '%d' and '%c' is %d" , c, c, ch - 0, cs);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
int cs = sum(c, ch - 0);
```

It looks like your trying to account for ASCII values by subtracting the ASCII value of 0 from whatever character the user enters. However, you used an integer literal of 0, when you'd want to use a character literal of '0'. See below:

```c
int cs = sum(c, ch - '0');
```

Also, I would recommend renaming your int to i or something other than c. It's a little difficult to distinguish that the types of c and ch are different.

Also consider changing

```c
if((c >= '0' && c <= '9')
```

to

```
if((c >= 0 && c <= 9)
```

c is an integer and you should compare it as such. By using ' ', you're basically doing a cast to a char variable which is unnecessary here.
Another problem is that I don't think you're going to be able to accomplish what you're trying to do using a char variable for a two-digit number. A char variable can hold a single character, where as a two-digit number is composed of, well, two characters.

Comment: Thank you! This did work. However, if the user enters a value greater than 9 where the character should be (Ex: 10 10), the result is "Character '10' represents a digit. Sum of '10' and '1' is 11". It seems to only be using the first digit (Ex: 10 20: Character '10' represents a digit. Sum of '10' and '2' is 12).

Comment: See my edit on that. Apologies, it looks like you were still making edits to your question as I was answering or I may have just missed that particular issue.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you for clarifying. I guess I will have to settle for the integer (where the character should be) being less than 10. I appreciate your efforts. Thank you for taking the time to assist a C noob.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment so I'm adding this answer for the problem abou t using only one digit.

You have a single char

```
char ch;
```

So it reads only one char, you need an array of chars like `char ch[10]`

Then you'd use `int foo = atoi(ch)` to converto your array to an integer

Comment: Thank you. I will read up on character arrays now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't [`atoi`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoq.3.html) expect a *nul-terminated* string as its argument? (also when performing string conversions use `strtol` as `atoi` provides zero error checking)

Comment: @MarkusZ Keep in mind that these two functions will convert your character array to an integer (or long integer), which means you would end up processing it the same way you processed your int c above. Not bad if you want to practice using library functions, but rather redundant as you can just have your user specify two integers from the get-go.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It stops at the first "not number" char. That would be the carriet return, wouldn't?

Comment: Nope, it would go screaming of across your stack until it accidentally found a zero (*nul*) character to indicate end-of-string `:)` Remember a "string" in C is always *nul-terminated*, e.g. `"Hi"` is actually `{ 'H', 'i', '\0' }`. Here `char ch` can not represent a string as it is a single character.

Comment: Fortunately [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) can take care of inserting that null-terminator!

Comment: Yep, but you still need more storage than 1-char. (and the variable needs to be a *pointer-to-char*). The only way `ch` can represent a string is the *empty-string* and only if you set `ch = 0;` and then take its address with `&ch` (not very useful).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but it's actually `char ch[10]` which is full of nulls already when created, isn't? (`char ch[10] = {0, 0, 0, ..., }` ?)
I've told him to use an array, not a single char

Comment: That's better, I was just going by what he has written in his question `char ch;`